# ordering activerecord object by most relevant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this query:

```
user_friends = current_user.friends.where('username like ?', "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

if I do a search for "bob" I may get "jobob" ahead of "bob" how can I organize these results in order of relevance.

I feel like I need to map them against regex but not clear on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a scope or a method on the User model.

But your biggest challenge is defining 'relevance'.